# Can I hash text based data and use that for imputation with scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hash, scikit-learn, imputation

I have a database full of research data sets that span from 1972 till today. Many of the older data sets are missing much of the meta-data that is now schima.org standard.

I was wondering if I could try hashing all of this and then using scikit-learn to impute the missing meta data with more complete ones. If not what else should I try?